Azure Signal R - Not acting as backplane as expected - cannot send message to specific user if not connected to same server
UPDATE:
Not the solution I was hoping for - but was able to accomplish desired outcome with serverless instead of default configuration
Followed these docs in case anyone else is interested
need to set up service manager and set it up as hosted service and custom negotiation endpoint but everything is working well not and have it all scaled out
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-use-management-sdk
https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/Management/NegotiationServer

ORIGINAL POST:
So we implemented Signal R on ASP.NET Core and used single server at first due to limitations with scaling
using default scenario not serverless
We discussed on implementing backplane or using Azure Signal R service - ended up going with Azure
The issue we are trying to solve for is when we need to send a message to a specific user through a controller

We have a microservice architecture
App A has Signal R hubs (user connects to) with multiple instances (5)
App B needs to send message to user connected to a hub on APP A (calls controller on App A with data to send)
If user is not connected to same server as the server App B connected to through load balancer when calling controller, message does not go through and gives error
If they connect to same server then it goes through as expected

I was under the impression Azure Signal R doubled as backplane to solve this issue
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-8.0

We set up service like this

We can successfully send a message to a user in a hub like this when connected to the same server (100% of the time in local)
[Authorize]
public class MyHub: Hub<IRateLockClient> {
    public async Task SendUpdateToUser(string username, List<RateLockUpdateModel> messages)
    {
        await Clients.User(username).ReceiveMessage(messages);
    }
}

It was my expectation that regardless of which app server the user is connected to (server 1) any server (ex server 2) could send a message to this user via Clients.User(username)
In current setup it seems this isn't the case - and connected users are still managed in app server instead of Azure signal R service
Is there any way around this? So that any app server can send to any specific user?
I've also tried using groups, but works the same - groups in my setup are app server dependent - so even if users are in same group - they cannot connect if on different servers
I'm hoping I am overlooking something here and can in fact target specific users or groups from any app server, otherwise I would just manage client connection in DB or backplane manually and not use Azure Signal R which I thought was supposed to help manage this scenario
